# How to set the coding system for new files with specific extensions

Tags: character-encoding, find-file

When I visit a new file, <kbd>^x</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, that has an extension of .sql or .dsql I would like the coding system to be set to `utf-8-with-signature-dos`. The default is currently `iso-latin-1-dos`.

I'm running `(version)` of `"GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)\n of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN"`

Both the .sql and .dsql extension start up sql-mode, but I doubt a hook off of sql mode is the appropriate place to change the coding system for new files.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use `prefer-coding-system`?

Comment: This is only case where I want to change coding system preferences.

Comment: Do you have files of this type that are not coded in this way?  It looks like you should be customizing `file-coding-system-alist`

Comment: Yes, there are some that are UTF-16. :(. I want to be intentional about changing those, so I don't want emacs to do it automagically.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Does `file-coding-system-alist` only apply to buffers for nonexistent files? I want to change just the default coding system for new files in general but not change existing ones, and the current answer seems more hacky than should be necessary.

Comment: @binki `file-coding-system-alist` applies to existing files, overriding emacs's standard file encoding detection. I saved a file in UTF-16, told `file-coding-system-alist` to use UTF-8 with that file type. Loaded the file and got `A^@ ^@F...` A UTF-16 byte stream interpreted as UTF-8.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Ah, then it’s definitely not suitable to solving this question and hacks are the only option.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a function and added to `find-file-not-found-functions`

```
(defun srs-set-new-sql-file-coding-system ()
  (with-current-buffer (current-buffer)
    (if (string-match "\\.d?sql\\'" buffer-file-name)
        (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-with-signature-dos)
      nil)))

(add-hook 'find-file-not-found-functions 'srs-set-new-sql-file-coding-system)
```